# VSD to ISD graph of MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, datasheet, voltage, body-diode

I want to compare two graphs provided in datasheets of two MOSFETs. Could anyone please explain what we can conclude if we compare both graphs? Which device has the better forward voltage drop of the intrinsic diode?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Pick a current level that's relevant to your application, maybe 100 A, or 400 A, and read off from each graph the voltage drop. Compare. Not sure what your issue is? That one has a log axis and the other linear doesn't help, but it doesn't hinder much either. If your problem is reading a log scale correctly, then just stick to the powers of 10. The difference in forward voltage at each of those currents is significant, so it's not even like you have a tricky interpolation to do on the graph.

Comment: Although the lower graph does seem to provide higher I/V across the range, if that’s what the OP needs (and usually it is)

Comment: @Neil_UK the values i got from graph are  0.85V  for 40A and 0.88V for 50A as compared to 0.69V for 40A and 0.71V for 50A. I just want to compare the datasheet to conclude which device has better body diode chracterstics for 40A 24V operation

Comment: @Frog Could you please Elaborate your comment. does it mean that lower graph has better body diode chracterstics? thanks

Comment: @Alison - Yes, the lower has much lower voltage drop at the same current. Its curve is much more exponential, while the upper one is more linear, as if the upper one is for a linear amplifier MOSFET and the lower one for a switching MOSFET.

Comment: @Alison by inspection the current in the lower graph is higher for a given voltage drop than the higher graph.  ‘Better’ is a subjective term but if it’s read as more amps per volt then yes it’s better.

Comment: @EdinFifić ok thanks for your comment. what impact it will have for a switching apllication. does this mean the body diode losses of higher graph will be higher than lower graph

Comment: @Frog Thanks. what we can conclude from these graphs in terms of losses within body diode

Comment: @Alison at a continuous 40A the power loss would be 28W cold or somewhat less as the device heats up.  I’d guess you won’t be running 40A DC through the body diode though.  The upper device would dissipate around 36W cold, for comparison.

Comment: @Alison Basically, if you have a lower voltage drop at the same current, that means you're dissipating less heat or wasting less power across that device (body diode in this case). Just read the graphs slowly and carefully. The switching losses also depend on the switching speed and whether the MOSFET is being used as an active diode so it bypasses the body diode most of the time. There are trade-offs in MOSFET production, and one characteristic may be better at the expense of another, like a lower RdsON in combination with a higher gate capacitance. There are "dynamic" characteristics also.